# Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence such as $|u_{n+1}-u_n|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ show that (U_n) is a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence such as $|u_{n+1}-u_n|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ show that (U_n) is a convergent sequence.

I m stuck with this question, I showed that $\lim\limits_{n \to \inf} u_{n+1}-u_n =0$ Can you help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To show that ${x_n}$ is convergent where $|x_{n+1} - x_n|< \frac{1}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322335/to-show-that-x-n-is-convergent-where-x-n1-x-n-frac1n2)

Comment: it's cauchy cause $|u_m-u_n| < \sum_{j=n}^m \frac{1}{j^2}$ goes to $0$ as $m,n \to \infty$.