# Prove or disprove that if $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<1/n$ then ${a_n }$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences

Prove or disprove that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<1/n$, then ${a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I encountered a similar question the other day, that question is about $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{n^2}$, then ${a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
I noticed that that one can be related to series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n^2}}$, and this series is convergent. However, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n}}$ is divergent, so I guess the answer is no.
But if it is false, I need to provide a explicit counterexample.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, this series is divergent. Because you sum on $k$, not on $n$. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A sequence $(a_n)$ such that $d(a_{n+1}, a_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ is called quasi-Cauchy sequence.

Exercise:

1. Every Cauchy sequence is quasi-Cauchy.
2. A quasi-Cauchy sequence need not be Cauchy $($Hint: $(a_n) =\sqrt{n}$ or $a_n=\log n)$

---

Your observation is correct✅

A quasi-Cauchy sequence $(a_n) $ where $d(a_{n+1}, a_n) $ can be dominated by the general term of a convergent series then the quasi-Cauchy would be a Cauchy sequence.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1322368/977780) for the proof.